# How to brute-force a login that uses passwords of a specific format?

Tags: brute-force, password-cracking, kali-linux

For example, if a website login that uses password of a specific format containing 3 letters and 3 numbers like abc123, qwr345, yta921...

What tools on Kali Linux can crack this type of password and what would the command be?

Comment: The tools on Kali are grouped conveniently to help with answering this question. There are also search functions to look for tools on Kali. Then you need to read the documentation once you find something.

Comment: This may help: https://tools.kali.org/tools-listing

Comment: FYI real world websites rarely have password format constraints that fit a pattern exactly like that; those are probably more often found in a CTF game.  Although I've seen some pretty terrible password policies, so I know it's not impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use [crunch](https://tools.kali.org/password-attacks/crunch). It can be configured to produce permutations that meet the rules you've mentioned.

Comment: Thanks did some research and found it was crunch 6 6 -t @@@%%%